# Cannot read email body with Spring: javax.mail.FolderClosedException

Tags: java, email, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to listen my Gmail inbox for incoming mails. Every time new mail arrives, I want to see it's subject and content.

So far, I have this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.internet.ContentType;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.commons.mail.util.MimeMessageParser;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.mail.transformer.MailToStringTransformer;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException;


public class GmailInboundImapIdleAdapterTestApp {
    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(GmailInboundImapIdleAdapterTestApp.class);

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/integration/gmail-imap-idle-config.xml");

        DirectChannel inputChannel = ac.getBean("receiveChannel", DirectChannel.class);

        inputChannel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message){
                    MimeMessage mm = (MimeMessage) message.getPayload();
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Subject: "+mm.getSubject());
                        System.out.println("Body: "+readPlainContent(mm));
                    } 
                    catch (javax.mail.MessagingException e) {

                        System.out.println("MessagingException: "+e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        });
    }

     private static String readHtmlContent(MimeMessage message) throws Exception {
            return new MimeMessageParser(message).parse().getHtmlContent();
        }

    private static String readPlainContent(MimeMessage message) throws Exception {
            return new MimeMessageParser(message).parse().getPlainContent();
        }
}
```

It can read the mail subject correctly. But no luck with mail body.`javax.mail.FolderClosedException` hit me. How to fix this?

Comment: You need to show your `gmail-imap-idle-config.xml`. Also, try setting `simple-content="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

As Gary said: `simple-content="true"` or since recently `autoCloseFolder = false`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mail.html#mail-inbound

> Starting with version 5.2, the `autoCloseFolder` option is provided on the mail receiver. Setting it to false doesn’t close the folder automatically after a fetch, but instead an `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE` header (see `MessageHeaderAccessor` API for more information) is populated into every message to producer from the channel adapter. It is the target application’s responsibility to call the `close()` on this header whenever it is necessary in the downstream flow: